# Get cartesian product of two columns

Tags: t-sql

How can I get the cartesian product of two columns in one table?

I have table

```
A    1
A    2
B    3
B    4
```

and I want a new table

```
A    1
A    2
A    3
A    4
B    1
B    2
B    3
B    4
```

Comment: What you need is a *self-join*, meaning you join a table to itself.

Answer (score 2):

[fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2bb8/1)

your table

[image]

`try this using joins`

```
select  distinct b.let,a.id from [dbo].[cartesian] a join [dbo].[cartesian] b on a.id<>b.id
```

will result like this [image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thank for `telling me` i made changes  @MarcoForberg

Answer (score 0):

Create this table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1]
(
  [A] [int] NOT NULL ,
  [B] [nvarchar](50) NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [A] ASC )
    WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
           ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
)
ON  [PRIMARY]
```

Fill table like this :

```
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
VALUES  ( 1, 'A' )
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
VALUES  ( 2, 'A' )
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
VALUES  ( 3, 'B' )
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
VALUES  ( 4, 'C' )

SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[Table_1]
```

[image]

Use this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.B ,
    T2.A
FROM    dbo.Table_1 AS T1 ,
    dbo.Table_1 AS T2
ORDER BY T1.B
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To clarify loup's answer (in more detail that allowable in a comment), any join with no relevant criteria specified will naturally produce a Cartesian product (which is why a glib answer to your question might be "all too easily"-- mistakenly doing t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.Key = t1.Key will produce the same result).

However, SQL Server does offer an explicit option to make your intentions known. The [CROSS JOIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) is essentially what you're looking for. But like INNER JOIN devolving to a Cartesian product without a useful join condition, CROSS JOIN devolves to a simple inner join if you go out of your way to add join criteria in the WHERE clause.

If this is a one-off operation, it probably doesn't matter which you use. But if you want to make it clear for posterity, consider CROSS JOIN instead.